# Blob list is not updating in react js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-storage

I have two components,

1. Uploader Component

   - Which uploads the file to Azure storage
2. ContainerList Component

   - Which fetches the uploaded file's data from Azure storage.

For fetching data from azure and show in ContainerList, I referred to ListBlobs in (https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html)

My components are completely independent components that were imported in a different react project by using npm-link. For npm link, I referred to this documentation (https://60devs.com/simple-way-to-manage-local-node-module-using-npm-link.html)

```
import {Uploader, ContainerList} from 'blobuploader';
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component{

      render(){
            return (
               <Uploader
                        accountName={azureCredentials.accountName} 
                        sasToken={azureCredentials.sasToken} 
                        multiple={true}/>

               <ContainerList 
                        accountName={azureCredentials.accountName} 
                        sasToken={azureCredentials.sasToken} />
             );
      }
}
```

The main issue is when I uploaded files to Azure storage by using the Uploader Component. Container List is not updating i.e the newly uploaded file to azure storage is not reflected in ContainerList. Need to reload the page for seeing updated data in ContainerList.

For example, you can see below the image where a new file has been uploaded but not showing in the list(i.e ContainerList)

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue. 
Thanks in advance

ContainerList code

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/containerList.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import PROGRESS from '../assets/progress.svg'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


class ContainerList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            datas: [],

         };
        this.blobService = null;
        this.initConnections.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/bundle/azure-storage.blob.js";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        script.onload = () => {
            this.initConnections();
        };
        console.log('script ended');
    }

    initConnections = () => {
        var accountName = this.props.accountName;
        var SasToken = this.props.sasToken;
        var blobUri = 'https://' + accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';
        this.blobService = this.blobService === null ? AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, SasToken) : this.blobService;
        this.blobService.getServiceProperties({options: ['clientRequestId']}, (error, result)=>{
            if(error){
                console.log('Error Creating Blob Service..')
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                this.blobService.listBlobsSegmented('my-con', null, {include:["metadata"]},  (error, results) => {
                 if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } 
                else {
                        var temp =[]

                        results.entries.map(async (ele,index) => {
                            console.log('Tag',ele);
                            var val = index+1;
                            var type = ele.contentSettings.contentType;

temp.push({number:val,name:ele.name,type,status:<button className='container-button'>PASS</button>,email:"testtagcheck123456@gmail.com",apiStatus:PROGRESS});
                                if(results.entries.length === temp.length){
                                    this.setState({datas:temp});
                                }

                        });


                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }


    render(){


//SHOWING DATA IN UI LIST FROM this.state.datas
        return (

            <div className= "table-box">
            <div className="table-row-head">
                 {  
                        (["No","File-Name","Type","Status","Outlook-Mail","API-Status"]).map((ele => {
                            return( ele === "No" ?<div className="table-cell table-head first-cell" style={{width:'4%'}}>
                            <p className ="heading-label">{ ele} </p>
                        </div> : <div className="table-cell table-head" style={{width:'20%'}}>
                            <p className="heading-label">{ ele} </p>
                        </div>)
                        })) 


                 }
            </div>
                { 
                    this.state.datas.map( (eles,index) => {

                       return (
                        <div className='table-row' key={index}>   
                        <div className="table-cell first-cell" style={{width:'4%'}}>
                            <p>{ eles.number} </p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="table-cell" style={{width:'23%'}} >
                            <p>{eles.name} </p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="table-cell"  style={{width:'20%'}} >
                            <p >{eles.type} </p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="table-cell" style={{width:'15%'}} >
                            <p>{eles.status} </p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="table-cell"  style={{width:'23%'}}>
                            <p>{eles.email} </p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="table-cell"  style={{width:'15%'}}>
                            <img src={eles.apiStatus} alt="PROGRESS" style={{width:'30%',}}/>
                        </div>

                        </div>
                    );

                    }

                    )

                }


        </div>


        );
    }


}

ContainerList.propTypes = {
    accountName: PropTypes.string,
    sasToken: PropTypes.string,
  }
export default ContainerList;
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code for `ContainerList` component?

Comment: sure @Gaurav Mantri

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri added code for ContainerList component you can see in initConnections I am connecting to azure by using account name and sastoken. Using browser method(this.blobService.listBlobsSegmented) getting blobs and finally storing all the blobs after iterating in state variable called datas

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. My guess is that your `ContainerList` component is not getting updated after you've uploaded a blob. You would need to pass some additional property to trigger an update on that component.

Comment: In other words, your `Uploader` needs to somehow tell `ContainerList` that it has uploaded something.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Mantri will try to modify.